# Reported Speech of wh-question: He wanted to know where he works/worked?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure which one we should use when we talk about someone asked:"**Where does he work?**"

> - He wanted to know where he works?
> - He wanted to know where he worked?

Does the answer depend on when the people asked?

Answer (score 2):

For the question **Where does he work?**, **He wanted to know where he works?** is more appropriate as both are in the present tense, whereas the other question is in the past tense and asking where the person works previously, not where they work now.